# DOM takes too long to react

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, dom

I'm trying to "GET" an image from a file every 100ms by changing the source of a DOM object. I can see that the GET call is indeed returning the correct image every 100ms, but the actual image display only updates once a second. Here's my JavaScript code that does the work:

```
<img id="videoDisplay" style="width:800; height:600"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function videoDataPoll(filename) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("videoDisplay").src = filename + "?random="+(new Date()).getTime();
      videoDataPoll(filename);
    }, 100);
  }
</script>
```

UPDATE: Changed the function to use preloading as follows:

```
<canvas id="videoDisplay" style="width:800; height:600"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var x=0, y=0;
  var canvas, context, img;
  function videoDataPoll() {
    var filename = getFilename();   
    canvas = document.getElementById("videoDisplay");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(img, x, y);
      setTimeout("videoDataPoll()", 100);
    }
    img.src = filename + "?random=" + (new Date()).getTime();
  }
<script>
```

Still updates at the same speed (which is actually every 5 seconds, not 1s as stated originally). So for every 50 get requests (10/sec for 5 seconds) the element only gets updated once.

Another important note: This second solution works perfectly on my localhost, where I run into the issue is when I'm running the same webpage off of a remote host.

Comment: You have to preload images before displaying. Otherwise, the 1s is the time when the image is loading. You can use [this function](http://short-tag.info/2013/04/preload-images-with-plain-javascript/).

Comment: After the first time that `videoDataPoll` is called, `filename` is

Comment: Haha, genius comment.

Comment: @undefined - nice use of display name. though make sure you do not change your name in future `;D`

Comment: My bad! Tried to take out unnecessary code bits for SO question simplification purposes, guess I took out a little too much. Filename is edited back into the question. Thanks for pointing that out @undefined!

Comment: What happens if for whatever reason (slow computer/network) it takes more than 100ms to download and render the image?

Comment: Noted @KevinB, you and a few others have helped teach me a lesson about onload today :).

Comment: a tricky attempt would be to "pre-save" the next src in another attribute on the same element like data-src="nextURL" and every 100ms you add the data-src value to src attribute and pre-save the next url to you data-src attribute, this way, i guess, the image will be loaded immediatly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use the onload handler for the image instead of a fixed timeout:

```
  function videoDataPoll(filename) {
      document.getElementById("videoDisplay").src = filename + "?random="+(new Date()).getTime();
  }

  document.getElementById("videoDisplay").onload = videoDataPoll;
  videoDataPoll(filename);
```

In this case you would need to get the filename from inside the function rather than passing it as a param.

Comment: I tried your solution, and I agree that it should work in theory, but unfortunately without the timeout the videoDataPoll just seems to spin out of control and freezes the web page.

Comment: @exxodus7 you can still use a timeout, but you should really wait for the onload before firing the timeout

Comment: Good point. I tried both together in my update to the answer, but it still had the same effect (as noted in the update, the badness only happens when I'm running on a remote host).

Comment: @exxodus7 This depends on how you update filename. On load should fire only once when the source is changed and the new image is loaded. At least in theory...

Comment: @exxodus7 I forgot to remove the videoDataPoll() call inside the actual function. That is the reason why you were getting the described behavior. Now I have updated.